# How to properly implement a sensor with SensorManager in a thread?

Tags: java, android

I've got this command on my thread, but it doesn't work: `sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);`

I want to make sensor background listener without my app being opened.

```java
public class myThread extends Thread implements SensorEventListener{
    public SensorManager sensorManager;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

I've got an error `Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(?)'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of an Activity, getSystemService() requires Context. Pass through a Context when initialising your thread and use context.getSystemService().

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

private Context context;
public SensorManager sensorManager;

public MyThread(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
/** In Activity **/ 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyThread(getContext()).start();
}
```

Comment: Hi. I added `Context context;` and `context.getSystemService(context.SENSOR_SERVICE);`, but now my application crashes when it starts the thread.

Comment: Thats because you've declared a context without actually having context. The context has to come from an activity or application. Unless you are using dagger and can inject the context, the simplest way would be to create a public constructor and pass in the context ie.
public myThread(Context context) {
this.context = contxt;
}

Comment: Hi again, and the same problem. I added 'Context context;
    public myThread(){this.context = MainActivity.contxt;}' into myThread and in MainActivity i added `public static Context contxt;`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The original answer has been updated with source code. That should work.